# ¿Como debe agrupar esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dias compañeros,

Tengo la siguiente tabla `co_orderdetail`

[image: Tabla co_orderdetail]

El detalle es que quiero listarlo en columnas el campo `ordercoin`

Lo he ejecutado así y me muestra este resultado:

```
SELECT 
id_order,
CASE ordercoin when 1 then coin end firstcoin,
CASE ordercoin when 2 then coin end seconcoin,
CASE ordercoin when 1 then monto end firstmonto,
CASE ordercoin when 2 then monto end seconmonto
FROM co_orderdetail
group by id_order,
CASE ordercoin when 1 then coin end,
CASE ordercoin when 2 then coin end,
CASE ordercoin when 1 then monto end ,
CASE ordercoin when 2 then monto end;
```

[image: Query]

## No quiero realizar ninguna sub consulta

El resultado que espero es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es el resultado exacto que esperas?

Comment: @ShadowPaz Tener solo 2 filas, agruparlos por el  `id_order`  excluyendo los nulos.

Comment: @ShadowPaz acabo de colocar el resultado que espero.

Comment: tienes que agregar un where dentro de tu consulta donde indiques que los valoes no sean igual a null, algo así como where campo is not null

Comment: Me gustaria saber cual es el motivo de querer hacer una consulta asi, ya que algo asi debe ser resulto por la vista mas que con un query. mas alla de eso, debes fijarte como hacer una tabla pivotante (pivot table), que no es simple ni trivial.

Comment: Es simple. Sin una sub-consulta no puedes mostrarlo como quieres. Porque quieres mostrar en un row el valor combinado.